# Cannot delete VPC or the network that the VPC is using

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to delete my VPC, but it says this:

[image]

It says one network interface must be deleted before the VPC can be deleted.

So I tried to delete the network interface, and it says this:

[image]

It makes me pay one to three dollars every month, and it is very annoying. Can anyone help me with how to delete the network or VPC?

Comment: You have to find the resource that uses the ENI. Delete the resource, then ENI and finally the VPC.

Comment: Can you share the details of the network interface? Where is it in use? Any EC2 instances etc.?